# Cutting Video on frames, save only every 3rd?

Tags: python, image, opencv, video

I tried to think about it, but because of new - it's doesn't work for me. 
Is anyone can help, what we should add here to be able save, for example, every 3rd or 5th frame?
Here is code

```
    import cv2
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvid.mp4')
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    count = 0;
    print "I am in success"
    while success:
      success,image = vidcap.read()
      if count % 3 == 0:
      cv2.imwrite("img_%3d.jpg" % count, image)     
      if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     
          break
      count += 1
```

Thank you very much for help in such silly question ^^'

Code for skip n frame's and save what you need. Example for every 3rd frame:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvid.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0;
print "I am in success"
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  if count % 3 == 0:
  cv2.imwrite("img_%3d.jpg" % count, image)     
  if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     
      break
  count += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to check if `count % 3 == 0`. However, there's another catch in your code

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvid.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0;

# number of frames to skip
numFrameToSave = 3

print "I am in success"
while success: # check success here might break your program
  success,image = vidcap.read() #success might be false and image might be None
  #check success here
  if not success:
    break

  # on every numFrameToSave 
  if (count % numFrameToSave ==0):
    cv2.imwrite("img_%3d.jpg" % count, image)   

  if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     
      break
  count += 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! To be honest, one min. ago found a solve of this problem, like you wrote count % 3 == 0.

Comment: Putting `success,image = vidcap.read()` from while loop at the end of loop remove the need to check for success inside loop because it will check it entering the loop. Another advantage is you dont have first frame drop like now, because of double reading (on line 3 and 11).

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/MyDrive/Front-Dash-Cam-1.m4v')
length = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print("Total frames in this vid :", length )
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
skipframes = 5 # no of frames to skip
print('started slicing..')
success = True
while success:
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  if (count % skipframes == 0):
    # print('slicing...')
    image  = cv2.resize(image, (256,256)) # resize frame
    cv2.imwrite("frames/frame_%3d.png" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
  if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
      break
  count += 1
print('finished..')
```